# External Javascript not working even though I linked it right(at least I am quite sure about that)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to web design and trying to build a responsive page using Bootstrap. Everything works except my linked JS. I am sure the path is right but neverthelast I tried to put my JS on server and indicated the full path through http:// but still not working. I even put all my scripts in the head section just in case but still not working. Start getting frustrated anyone please can help me guys :) The JS is in the 'scripts' folder which is in the same folder with my 'index.html'.

This is my html in the head section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

And here is my external JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu").slideUp("slow");

});
```

Comment: any error in browser console? If the link is not right, the slideUp should prompt u an error in your browser console

Comment: I belive it should be src="/scripts/script.js"

Comment: Do you have the url link?

Comment: @Medo, you don't know where the root of the site is so that may not work. The relative URL shown matches directory description

Comment: src="/scripts/script.js" didn't work guys. The browser doesn't through any errors just the menu doesn't slide up. Yes the url that I used is src="http://greenetti.ru/1/script.js"

Comment: your link seems to correct. Check your console once for any JavaScript error. Else put a debugger inside your document ready and check whether your slide up is attached to menu Dom.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! I was having some Windows OS issues, reinstalled Linux OS and now everything works. Now I am a linux user! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is loading in the jQuery. It's trying to load your first script from a relative path. Try replacing the first script with           `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script> Still not working

Comment: I tried to use the local jQuery in the same folder 'scripts': <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="scripts/script.js"></script> Still no result :(

Comment: I was just wondering if it has something to do with the Bootstrap

Comment: When you are loading scripts externally you need to make sure you have http:// in front of the link.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I used: <script src='[link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js)'></script> Still nothing happens. I do use http:// in front of the link

Comment: <script src="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/…;
That is missing http:// and isn't closed out.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! I was having some Windows OS issues, reinstalled Linux OS and now everything works. Now I am a linux user! :)